.env paths from environment docker-compose block in Nuxt3 are not applied
i have to use this code in my app in nuxt.config.ts:
runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            path: process.env.PATH || "",
        },
    },

    routeRules: {
        '/api/**': {
            proxy: { to: `${process.env.PATH}/api/**` },
         },
    },


But path ${process.env.PATH}/api/** can't be changed if i apply docker-compose environment:
services:
  app:
    image: app:v0.1
    container_name: "app"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      PATH: http://localhost:3000

How to do that?
I wanted to use useRuntimeConfig(), but it can't be applied in nuxt.config.ts

PATH is a system environment. You should use some other env variable to prevent conflict.
